# Law of unconscious statistician for conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I have random variables $X$, $Y$ with joint distribution $f_{XY}(x,y)$ and conditional distribution $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ and another random variable $Z=g(X)$ with $g$ being bijective is it true that

$$E(Z|Y=y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f_{X|Y}(x|y)dx$$

if so, does $g$ need to be bijective for this to hold in general? If not, is there a way to find $E(Z|Y=y)$ knowing just the joint and conditional probability functions for $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: The short answer is: Yes it does hold regardless of wheter $g$ is bijective or not.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen so then for general $Z=g(X,Y)$, $E(Z|Y=y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x,y)f_{X|Y}(x,y)dx$ since $E(g(X,Y)|Y=y)=E(g(X,y)|Y=y)$ and $y$ is essentially a parameter for the computation above in the question?

Comment: It’s definitely true for every Borel function $g$ with $E|g(X)| < +\infty$